# stty in non interactive mode

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, stty

I am executing a command through script in remote server which is of non-interactive mode. I've gone through the link and found the below errror is because of running stty in non-interactive mode.[URL="http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.shell/stty-invalid-argument-using-ssh/506594"]http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.shell/stty-invalid-argument-using-ssh/506594[/URL]

```
stty -echo 
useradd <useraname> -m <password>
stty echo
```

stty is used not to show passwords in terminal. But i am getting 
stty: standard input: Invalid argument
as in output.

How to get rid of/overcome this error in my output.

Comment: `stty` works fine in non-interactive scripts. It's a script (interactive or not) that is not connected to a controlling tty that is going to have problems with `stty`. Non-interactive is not necessarily equivalent to "no controlling tty"...

Answer (score 1):

`echo` is for whether locally typed characters are displayed on the screen or not (as far as I know).

I don't believe that does anything for a script that includes a password in it already.

So you can probably just remove those two `stty` lines entirely as they aren't doing anything useful for you to begin with.

Alternatively, if, for some reason, there is (or you believe there is) a reason to keep those lines you should be able to add `2>/dev/null` to those commands to silence the error output.